# [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, cloudera, impala

I'm getting the following error while executing queries against a database in impala. With other databases its working fine.

Error trace is as follows.

```
[Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: select * from test_table limit 1, SQL state: {1}, Query: {2}.[]
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: [Simba][JSQLEngine](12010) The table "test_table"    could not be found., SQL state: HY000, Query: select count(*) from test_table.
            at     com.cloudera.impala.hivecommon.dataengine.HiveJDBCDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
            at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeNoParams(Unknown Source)
            at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.cloudera.impala.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: [Simba][JSQLEngine](12010) The table "test_table" could not be found., SQL state: HY000, Query: select count(*) from test_table.
            ... 3 more
```

if I execute `show tables` its listing the table name.

If I execute it from hue its not displaying anything in the result.

I tried by invalidating the metadata.

I tried by changing to latest driver `jdbc41` same problem.

Where might be the problem?

Comment: If you use the native query mode in the driver, do you get the same error?

Comment: yes, its not the driver issue actually it seems some problem with impala.

Comment: Is the table in a different schema, which might require it to be fully qualified? Does the table show up when you inspect the table catalog metadata?

Comment: I think @KylePorter has it -- I cannot find a way to avoid having to fully qualify the table name with it's scope (a.k.a database).  If you only have one scope/db it may be possible to specify that in the JDBC connection string, e.g. `jdbc::impala://<host>:21050/<db-name>` -- the default scope is called `default`, so try that.  If you're not able to see a result from Hue (which requires you to specify the scope), then something else is likely wrong.

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr,KylePorter, thanks for help, the problem was in the .avro file format. My teamlead has fixed it, Not sure what he has done he just said it was the problem of file format.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was caused by not having a /user/scott directory on hdfs with write permissions for the Hiveserver (running as cloudera-scm user)(my jdbc connection uses scott as the user id). Once I created the dir and chmod'ed it, I could run all queries. Earlier only select * worked but select count(*) did not.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. hadoop fs -mkdir /user/my_user/ && hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/my_user/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the .avro file format. My teamlead has fixed it, Not sure what he has done he just said it was the problem of file format.